# How to install interpreter on pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, installation

Python version: 3.6
Pycharm: community edition 2017.3.4
When i am trying to install an interpreter in pycharm
 [but the "+" button is not available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgRME.png)

When i clicked on the "Install packaging tools" at the bottom [it displays an error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnXhx.png)

So i follow some instructions and download pip and setuptools and try to get them installed,however error messages just keep popping up.
[no module named setuptools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ANttK.png) //
[no module named pip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9fOA.png)

I'm new to python and have no idea what is going on... Please help...

---

Error message when i tried to check pip version on CMD:

> C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip --version
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "runpy.py", line 193, in
>   _run_module_as_main
>   File "runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
>   File "C:\Python\Scripts\pip.exe__main__.py", line 5, in 
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'

---

I have uninstall pycharm and re-installed again, thing is getting worsen.
When I clicked add base interpreter, there always an error message pop up:

> "Error: Standard Python 'venv' module not found"
>   What does it mean??

Comment: Under my Python\Scripts directory, I have easy_install, easy_install-3.6, pip, pip3.6 and pip3, does this mean I already have pip installed?

Comment: Please add you error messages as formatted text instead of an image.

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

```
1. GoTo 'settings' and 'Project Interpreter'
2. Click on 'Add' and you will get a pop-up.
3. Select 'New environment' and for 'Base interpreter' add the 'python.exe' location from the python3.6 directory of your local drive.
4. click 'Ok'
5. Then you can select the required packages by clicking '+' and searching for package name
```

Comment: When I clicked OK , an error message pops "Error: Standard Python 'venv' module not found".

Comment: Click on 'wheel' button next to project interpreter and then click on 'Add' and you will get pop up window to create 'New environment' or to use 'Existing environment'. Select 'New environment' and for base interpreter select the 'python.exe' file from the python3.6 directory.

Comment: Yes I did so, is there any requirement for location field? I entered a random location and "
Error: Standard Python 'venv' module not found" is what I get.

Comment: Usually when we select any location the pycharm creates directories like 'Include', 'Lib', 'scripts'..... So you can select any location and make sure it doesn't contain venv directories (Include, Lib, scripts ). It is better to select an empty directory for 'Location'

Comment: Yes. I just created an empty folder in C:\ and set it as the location, " Error: Standard Python 'venv' module not found" is still popping up.

Comment: If possible could you please add screenshots here

Comment: Thanks for your kind help, i have resolved the issue by just downloading an Anaconda and set it as the interpreter. And it works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @kvmahesh for your help however i have solved the problem in another way.

I basically just downloaded an Anocanda and set the interpreter to Anocanda instead of python and everything is settled. Seems like there are some files missing with my Python3.

Hope this help with whoever is encountering the same issue.